# Use ruby to convert the exif gps data array format to latitude and longitude floats

Tags: ruby, gps

When you retrieve exif data from a file, the coordinates are given to you in an array of 3 numbers.

```
i.exif['gps_latitude']
=> ["6/1", "4/1", "911/50"]
```

This needs to be converted to the more common float format for general use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straight forward way I can think of is to convert the strings to [`Rational`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Rational.html) numbers:

```
arr = ["6/1", "4/1", "911/50"]

d, m, s = arr.map(&:to_r)
#=> [(6/1), (4/1), (911/50)]
```

And calculate the value of decimal degrees via:

```
lat = d + m / 60 + s / 3600
#=> (1092911/180000)
```

To obtain a float value:

```
lat.to_f
#=> 6.071727777777777
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to make the conversion in ruby:

```
arr = exif.gps_latitude
pic.lat = arr[0].to_f + arr[1].to_f/60 + arr[2].to_f/3600
pic.lat *= exif.gps_latitude_ref == 'S' ? -1 : 1

arr = exif.gps_longitude
pic.lng = arr[0].to_f + arr[1].to_f/60 + arr[2].to_f/3600
pic.lng *= exif.gps_longitude_ref == 'W' ? -1 : 1
```

Comment: This code ignores the denominator, e.g. `50`. The 3 numbers translate to `6° 4′ 18.22″`, not `6° 4′ 911″`